# Injecting implicits in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

I have the following traits:

```
trait Tr1 {
  implicit val i: Int
}

trait Ctx { tr: Tr1 =>
  def test: Int = implicitly[Int]
}
```

And now I'm running my application as follows:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val ctx: Ctx = new Ctx with Tr1 {
      override implicit val i: Int = 123
    }
    println(ctx.test) //prints 123!!!
  }
```

Surprisingly it prints `123`. I thought that we have `val i` deafultly initialized to `0` but compiler figured out that we have and instance which overrides `implicit val i: Int` to the value `123`.

Now I'm confused about implicit resolution in such cases. Can you please exaplain?

Answer (score 1):

`trait Ctx { tr: Tr1` it's a  **self type**, it means it requires `Tr1` for `Ctx` like `extend` it, and `implicitly[Int]` it's trying to find a **implicit Int** variable. Since `Tr1` has defined a **implicit val i** variable, so **compiler** can infer `implicitly[Int]` is **implicit val i** in current scope.

So when you override `implicit val i: Int = 123`, the `test` method will return `123`.